# I want to display a div on the mouseClick Coordinates

Tags: css, reactjs

The div is actually a modal, I am using tailwind CSS with this

```
<div className={( displayModal ? 'block' : 'hidden' ) + ` w-screen h-screen absolute top-${hereIWantToPlaceXValueInPx} left=${hereIWantToPlaceYInPx} z-20 grid`}>
</div>
```

I want these pixel values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the click event and then get the necessary coordinates from the event body, depending on your implementation, these are either `screenX` and `screenY` or `clientY` and `clientX`:

```js
const [position, setPosition] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (event) => {
      // or event.clientY and event.clientX
      setPosition({
        x: event.screenX,
        y: event.screenY,
      });
    };

    window.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: As you mentioned in your answer `setPosition({ x: event.screenX,
 y: event.screenY, });`  **x** and **y** position as an object. so, `position` should also be initiated as an object not single value. isn't it?

Comment: @nuser137 Yes, you're right, I'll fix it now

Answer (score 1):

You could store the mouse position in the state as an object and then use it when you return your `JSX`.

The idea is simple, you'll have a state named, for example, `mousePos` that is an object initialized as `{x: 0, y: 0}` (or whatever suits you) then you listen for the click event on the `window` to update your state which you can use to directly change the values in your `className` string.

```js
const MyComponent = props => {
  const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // the click handler that updates the position state variable
    const clickHandler = e => setMousePos({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY,
    });

    // listen for the click event on the window
    window.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

    // on unmount simply remove the click listener
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  }, []);
  return (
      <div className = {`${props.displayModal ? 'block' : 'hidden'} w-screen h-screen absolute top-${mousePos.x} left=${mousePos.y} z-20 grid`}>
          I Am a model! 
      </div>;
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

You might also create a custom hook that allows you to get the mouse position on any component you need, something like:

```js
export default function useMousePosition() {
  const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const clickHandler = e => setMousePos({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY,
    });
    window.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  }, []);
  return mousePos;
}

// then use it as follow in your components
//   const mousePos = useMousePos();
```